# add additionalScrapeConfigs into Prometheus service in K8s

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

Kubectl Version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.2", GitCommit:"092fbfbf53427de67cac1e9fa54aaa09a28371d7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:59:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.11", GitCommit:"c6a2f08fc4378c5381dd948d9ad9d1080e3e6b33", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-13T17:14:18Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I created a prometheus-values.yaml file with following key content:

```
defaultRules:
  create: true
  rules:
    alertmanager: false
    etcd: true
    general: true
    k8s: true
    kubeApiserver: true
    kubePrometheusNodeAlerting: true
    kubePrometheusNodeRecording: true
    kubernetesAbsent: true
    kubernetesApps: true
    kubernetesResources: true
    kubernetesStorage: true
    kubernetesSystem: true
    kubeScheduler: true
    network: true
    node: true
    prometheus: true
    prometheusOperator: true
    time: true

  ## Labels for default rules
  labels: {}
  ## Annotations for default rules
  annotations:
    priority: 'high'


kubeControllerManager:
  enabled: true
  serviceMonitor:
    https: false
    insecureSkipVerify: true

kubelet:
  enabled: true
  serviceMonitor:
    https: false

prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    externalUrl: 'https://myapp-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/prometheus/'
    routePrefix: '/prometheus'
  podDisruptionBudget:
    enabled: true
    minAvailable: 1
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
      # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: admin
      # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Authentication Required - ok"

    tls: 
      # - secretName: cluster1
      - hosts: 
          - myapp-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
    hosts:
      - myapp-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
    # path: "/prometheus/"
    paths: 
      - "/prometheus/"
    pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  
  prometheusSpec:
    additionalScrapeConfigs:
      - job_name: myapp_cluster
        metrics_path: /MyApp/Metrics
        basic_auth:
          username: prometheus
          password: MyAppPass
        # static_configs:
        #   - targets: ["10.244.0.5:8080"]
        scrape_interval: 15s
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: endpoints
            namespaces:
              names:
              - myapp-ha
        relabel_configs:
          - action: keep
            source_labels:
            - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
            regex: myapp-svc
          - action: keep
            source_labels:
            - __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name
            regex: HTTP
```

Grafana setting was removed for simplicity and then I use following command to deploy prometheus:

```
helm install prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --values prometheus_values.yaml
```

If I remove section `prometheusSpec`, I can access prometheus via: 'https://myapp-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/prometheus/'.

However, if I include `prometheusSpec` as showing above, I will get `404 page not found` from the same link access.

Meanwhile, I use the command:

```
kubectl exec -it prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-0 -- cat /etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml
```

to check the prometheus configuration and it looks correct.

When I use command `kubectl get endpoints`, I can see endpoint `myapp-svc` has value: `10.244.0.5:8080,10.244.1.8:8080,10.244.2.7:8080`

Appreciate someone can share with me a workable configuration of 'additionalScrapeConfigs`either via`endpoints`or`pod`of`kubernetes_sd_configs`

Comment: Hello @Windchill. Have you considered using [this approach](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/additional-scrape-config.md#additional-scrape-configuration)?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor, thank you, Yes, indeed I tried that approach first and it doesn't work either. At the end, I forked helm-charts repo and directly modified values.yaml and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As already confirmed in the comments, the solution was to fork the helm charts and directly modify `values.yaml`.